# For loop through an array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, loops, variables, for-loop

I need to loop through an array and create 8 variable p1, p2, p3 etc.

```
<?php    
 for ($z =0; $z < 7; $z++) {
     echo ' var p '.($z + 1).$gamelistarray[$z+1][4]. "<br>";
}
    ?>
```

This is the code that I have but I dont know how to progress it or what is wrong?

Comment: If you need to create numbered variables from an array, you're doing something wrong

Comment: If you can't explain HOW this code isn't working, why should we try and GUESS what the problem might be?

Comment: Are you trying to write javascript code or create PHP variable?

Comment: Not necessarily numbered variables, I just need eight separate variables as the original data comes from a table.

Comment: Maybe you should expand on what you are ACTUALLY trying to do, so we can attempt something better than a guess

Comment: @MarcB I understand the code, but I dont know what I need to change

Comment: _What you need to change_ **to do what** We are not **clairevoyant**

Comment: change **WHAT**? We have no idea what you're trying to accomplish. e.g. what SHOULD the output look like?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Most of the code is javascript but this loop is PHP. I have an array which contains data from a table and I need to print this into a table on a website. Theres 7 names I need to print.

Comment: What is the `var` for, thats what made me think javascript

Comment: So show us an example of this array you know all about **but we are completely ignorant of** Again **not clairvoyant** but definitely getting to think this is a close vote as _Unclear what you are asking_

Comment: @MarcB Sorry haha, Im new to javascript. The loop currently does not work and I dont know why, I dont know if this helps but its what I mean.

Comment: again. does not work **HOW**? You get an error? you get nothing? you get bad output? you get mangled output? The code kicked your dog and insulted your mother? But if you're generating javascript, then what you're spitting out is **NOT** javascript. `<br>` is **NOT** javascript. that's  html

Comment: Enough is enough Close voted. This is a waste of everybodies time. Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to make JavaScript varibales `p1` through `p8` and assign a value to them, I would do this:

```
<?php    
for ($z=1; $z < 8; $z++) {
    echo "var p$z = '{$gamelistarray[$z][4]}';\r\n";
}
?>
```

Faster and flexible:

```
<?php    
$z = 1;
foreach($gamelistarray as $gl){
    echo "var p$z = '{$gl[4]}';\r\n";
    $z++;
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This worked!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.